# How can I access angularjs form elements using java-selenium webdriver?

Tags: angularjs, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

How can I access the form elements like **ng-repeat** for automating web applications with front end angularjs using **java-selenium Webdriver**. I was able to automate most of the things in the web application with this with the help of xpath. Now situation came where I have to do auto generated quizzes where the number of questions, the question type, etc can vary depending upon the quiz type.
Now I have to access the data-ng-repeat index count. The html of the same is given below, please help me to get the index count here.

```html
<div class="margin-top-30">
   <!-- <div class="progress-box time-header-font-2 text-center open-sans" 
      ng-repeat="x in [1,2,3,4,5,6,7] track by $index">{{x}}
       </div> -->
   <!-- ngRepeat: assessment in assessmentData -->
   <div data-ng-repeat="assessment in assessmentData" class="progress-box time-header-font-2 text-center pointer-cursor open-sans legend-0" data-ng-click="loadRandomQuestion($index)" style="">1</div>
   <!-- end ngRepeat: assessment in assessmentData -->
   <div data-ng-repeat="assessment in assessmentData" class="progress-box time-header-font-2 text-center pointer-cursor open-sans legend-0" data-ng-click="loadRandomQuestion($index)">2</div>
   <!-- end ngRepeat: assessment in assessmentData -->
   <div data-ng-repeat="assessment in assessmentData" class="progress-box time-header-font-2 text-center pointer-cursor open-sans legend-0" data-ng-click="loadRandomQuestion($index)">3</div>
   <!-- end ngRepeat: assessment in assessmentData -->
   <div data-ng-repeat="assessment in assessmentData" class="progress-box time-header-font-2 text-center pointer-cursor open-sans legend-0" data-ng-click="loadRandomQuestion($index)">4</div>
   <!-- end ngRepeat: assessment in assessmentData -->
   <div data-ng-repeat="assessment in assessmentData" class="progress-box time-header-font-2 text-center pointer-cursor open-sans legend-0" data-ng-click="loadRandomQuestion($index)">5</div>
   <!-- end ngRepeat: assessment in assessmentData --> 
</div>
<div class="col-sm-12 padding-snip">
   <div data-ng-show="finish_quiz" class="finish-quiz-btn text-center ng-hide" style="">
      <span class="time-header-font-1 open-sans"><span translate="portallang_finishQuiz" class="ng-scope">FINISH QUIZ</span></span>
   </div>
   <!-- <div ng-if="count+1 >= totalQuestions" class="finish-quiz-btn text-center pointer-cursor legend-1" ng-click="stop();">
      <span class="time-header-font-1 open-sans">FINISH QUIZ</span>
      </div> -->
</div>
```

Comment: Please add script language tag ,like java, javascript, python

Comment: Are you trying to get the value of `$index`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java

```
List<WebElement> list = driver.findElements(
       By.cssSelector("div[data-ng-repeat='assessment in assessmentData']"));
String script = "angular.element(arguments[0]).scope().$index";

for(WebElement item:list) {
    String index = ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript(script, item).toString();
    System.out.println("text: " + item.getText());
    System.out.println("index: " + index);
}
```

Comment: That's not going to work for a production build where you can't access `.scope()`.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to get the value of `$index` change your `ng-repeat` to include a `data-` attribute with the value. Have a look at [`ng-attr`](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/interpolation#-ngattr-for-binding-to-arbitrary-attributes).

```
<div class="progress-box time-header-font-2 text-center open-sans" 
    ng-repeat="x in [1,2,3,4,5,6,7] track by $index"
    ng-attr-data-index="{{ $index }}"
>
```